# Condition SUM in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I want to calculate con_Amount field & want to put total to D01,D02,....D31 on the condition of Con_PubDate. 
if Con_PubDate field Day = 1 then I want to put the total to D01,if Con_PubDate field Day = 2 then I want to put the total to D02,likewise upto Day = 31 then I want to put the total to D31

I try following code in stored procedure but it had an error. Some one please help me to solve this problem.

```
SELECT Con_Cnt_Code,
       Con_Dst_Code,
       Con_Cor_Code,
       SUM(CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 1 THEN con_Amount
       ELSE
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 2 THEN con_Amount
            ELSE
                 SUM(CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 31 THEN con_Amount
                END) AS D31
            END) AS D02
        END) AS D01
 FROM Contributions 
 GROUP BY Con_Cnt_Code,Con_Dst_Code,Con_Cor_Code
```

Comment: "but it had an error" – please be more specific.

Comment: If you get an error, at least show us the error message!

Comment: Dont nest all case into 1 column, just split it to 31 column with 31 `case expressions`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Also please tell us what server you're using, as different servers may implement SQL differently. It's unfortunately not as standardized as one would hope always.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `DATEPART` looks like SQL Server, but this question is fairly DB agnostic, from what I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want each conditional sum of a `CASE` expression as a separate item in your select list, something like this:

```
SELECT
    Con_Cnt_Code,
    Con_Dst_Code,
    Con_Cor_Code,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 1  THEN con_Amount END) AS D01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 2  THEN con_Amount END) AS D02,
    -- and possibly other days as well
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,Con_PubDate) = 31 THEN con_Amount END) AS D31
FROM Contributions
GROUP BY
    Con_Cnt_Code, Con_Dst_Code, Con_Cor_Code;
```

By default, `SUM` will ignore `NULL` values, so you might not need an `ELSE` condition in your `CASE` expressions.  If you add one, you may default the amount to sum to zero.